# MySQL table disk layout

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I am new to MySQL and I'm trying to understand the physical layout of records on disk.

For example, in Postgres the the CTID indicates where in physical storage each row (tuple) is stored. Is there a similar field for MySQL that indicates how records are stored in memory or are they mainly stored in order of the defined primary key?

Comment: MySQL has a variety of _storage-engines_ (MyISAM, InnoDB, etc) which have their own layouts, btw.

Comment: I see. I was wondering what the case was for the most popular storage enginers (which I think are MyISAM or InnoDB)?

Comment: [MyISAM's _three_ table formats are documented here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/myisam-table-formats.html) and [InnoDB's is here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-on-disk-structures.html)